# separating socket on another class on Android studio

Tags: android, class, android-studio

I am creating my socket program on my main activity on Android Studio. Now I want to separate the socket portion by creating another class that will be called by my main activity.  Need help.  This is some part of my codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket client;
    private Button Connect,Disconnect;
    EditText editTextAddress;
    private TextView textResponse;
    private BufferedReader BufferIn;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        Disconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);
        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address); 
        textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);


        Disconnect.setOnClickListener(DisconnectOnClickListener);
        Connect.setOnClickListener(ConnectOnClickListener);

    }

    //Button Disconnect
    OnClickListener DisconnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(client !=null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) { /* failed */ }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "socket not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    };





    //Button Connect
    OnClickListener ConnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mConnectAndPoll.start();

        }
    };


    private final Thread mConnectAndPoll = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        String serverm = null;
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                final String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString();

                client = new Socket(address, 8080);
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                while (mRun) {
                    serverm = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (serverm != null) {
                        System.out.println(serverm);

                    }
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Write Thread code in separate class like:

**MyThread**

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{

    String serverm = null;
    String address;
    Socket client;
    Context context;

    public MyThread (String address, Context context )
    {
        this.address = address;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void stopSocket()
    {
        if(client !=null) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                client.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "socket not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {


            client = new Socket(address, 8080);
            BufferedReader mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            while (mRun) {
                serverm = mBufferIn.readLine();

                if (serverm != null) {
                    System.out.println(serverm);

                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button Connect,Disconnect;
    EditText editTextAddress;
    private TextView textResponse;
    private BufferedReader BufferIn;

    MyThread thread;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
        Disconnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disconnect);
        editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address); 
        textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);    

        Disconnect.setOnClickListener(DisconnectOnClickListener);
        Connect.setOnClickListener(ConnectOnClickListener);

    }

    //Button Disconnect
    OnClickListener DisconnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {    
        public void onClick(View v) {  
            thread.stopSocket();    
        }
    };   

    //Button Connect
    OnClickListener ConnectOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {    

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            thread = new MyThread(editTextAddress.getText().toString(), getApplicationContext());
            thread.start();

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: How can I call it? I use new MyThread(stopSocket).start(); but it didn't work.